# Is there a way to use hql without classes?

Tags: hibernate

The scenario is: in my system, the user will be able to define a query to a database using some kind of metadata.

Example: the user will define some parameters such as:

```
 -DatabaseType: Oracle 11g
 -ConnectionProperties: (user, password, server, etc)
 -TableName: TAB1
 -Columns: COL1, COL2
 -Filters: COL3=2 ; COL2=5
```

That way, I don't know previously what will be returned, and thus I don't have a class that matches the resultSet returned by this query.

That said, the problem is: can I build a HQL query using these "metadata" even without a class that match the result (like TAB1 with COL1 and COL2)?

FAQ: -"Why do you want to use HQL and not SQL" Answer: to be database-independent.

Thanks, and please tell me if I wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score 1):

HQL operates on objects, so no - hibernate will complain that it doesn't find the object you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is database independence, you can go quite far along with JDBC escape sequences. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/jdbc_drivers/sqlescape.html for the overview.

Comment: Great! Seems like a possible solution for my problem. Thank you for the tip! ;)